Unexpected workload after Visual Studio install
I'm looking for anyone to elucidate why, on the same machine, using the exact same install script for Visual studio 2022, the newest version (17.12.35521.163) comes with an older maui-windows workload (7.0.49/7.0.100) while a previous version (17.11.35222.181) comes with a newer maui-windows workload (8.0.72/8.0.100).
If anyone can offer an explanation, and perhaps even some clarity on what "workload-sets" are vis-a-vis SDKs, manifests, nuget etc. I'd be grateful.
